# Cor de código HTML dentro de string no PhpStorm

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

Quando insiro um echo ou uma variável PHP recebendo uma string com código HTML, o PhpStorm não fica na cor padrão que seria tudo amarelo, como no Sublime por exemplo, e isso acaba confundindo bastante na hora de analisar o código. Exemplo:

[image: tela do PhpStorm mostrando string em várias cores]

Onde posso alterar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver desabilitando o Language Injections em Configurações, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Para trocar as cores das palvras chaves acesse:`File>Settings>Colors & fonts>PHP`. No lado direito selecione `Strings` mais ao lado esquerdo estará o botão que troca a cor.

[image: File>Settings>Colors & fonts>PHP]

Comment: Já desmarquei o Inherit e setei a cor amarela, mas no caso da string HTML isso não se aplica.

Comment: @tiaguinhow, as cores da sessão `html` você também mudou?

Comment: somente a tag e tag name